# W-Buffer(ing) in Direct3D 12

Tags: buffer, direct3d12

On the D3D10 Docs is a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-api-features-deprecated) which shows the deprecated features from D3D9 to D3D10. It says that W buffering is no longer supported and we should use high-precision depth buffers/Z-Buffers instead. I suspect that it is also not (fully) supported in Direct3D 11 and 12. But is there any way to use W-buffers in Direct3D 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "W-buffering" feature in Direct3D 9 is part of the legacy fixed-function pipeline. In Direct3D 10 and later, you can only use the programmable shader pipeline (or for DirectX 11+ the DirectCompute shader pipeline). Therefore, the 'w-buffering' hardware feature isn't relevant. This was also much more of an issue with Direct3D 9 era hardware when people were using 16-bit depth buffers.

In the programmable shader model, it's up to your shaders to compute depth values using either conventional z or linearized-depth values, and set the appropriate depth/stencil state. Beware that you need to use `SV_DepthGreater` or `SV_DepthLessEqual` instead of `SV_Depth` to not lose 'early z rejection' optimizations.

See [this blog post](http://dev.theomader.com/linear-depth/) and [this post](https://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/d3d11-features/) for a good discussion of the topic.

**TL;DR:** Most people just use `DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT` and don't worry about it.

Comment: Does Z-Fighting also occur when using SV_Depth?

Comment: Z fighting can happen anytime you have insufficient precision in the depth-buffer for your near/far plane settings. It's just much less of an issue when using  ``DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT`` instead of the old 16-bit depth formats.